# Android java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, cursor, onclick, gallery

I wrote an android app and so far it works perfect except for on one phone.  It is the exact phone that I have with 2.2 on both phones and mine works perfect.  The other phone is getting force close all the time but only when opening an activity that queries my image DB and tries to show a gallery.  Every activity crashes in the same place, the viewimages.  At first I thought it was the intent that was doing it but one of the activitys does not have the intent, it opens the images below the gallery.  This works on the emulator, on my moto droid and on a few other different droids.  Here is the code for the gallery and my bitmap decoder.  The error is below that.  If anyone can see anything that would make it crash I would really appreciate the help.

```
public void viewimages() {

    String [] proj={ImageProvider._ID, ImageProvider.IMAGE, ImageProvider.TABLENAME,
            ImageProvider.ITEMID, ImageProvider.IMAGEDATE};

    cursor = managedQuery(ImageProvider.CONTENT_URI,
        proj,
        ImageProvider.TABLENAME + "=" + "'" + Tablename + "'"
    + " and " + ImageProvider.ITEMID + "=" + "'" + ID + "'",
        null,
        ImageProvider.IMAGEDATE);
```

Line 182 ->       column_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(ImageProvider._ID);

```
    g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            ImageID = cursor.getLong(column_index);
            Intent i = new Intent(LivestockDetails.this, ImageViewer.class);
            i.putExtra("id", ImageID);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

private Bitmap decodeFile(String file){
    Bitmap b = null;
    //Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, o);
    int scale = 1;
    if (o.outHeight > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE || o.outWidth > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
        scale = 2 ^ (int) Math.ceil(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5));
    }

    //Decode with inSampleSize 
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
    o2.inSampleSize = scale; 
    b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, o2); 
    return b; 
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;

        TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
        mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
        if (convertView == null) {

            String [] proj={ImageProvider._ID, ImageProvider.IMAGE, ImageProvider.TABLENAME, 
                    ImageProvider.ITEMID, ImageProvider.IMAGEDATE};

            cursor = managedQuery(ImageProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                proj,
                ImageProvider.TABLENAME + "=" + "'" + Tablename + "'"
                + " and " + ImageProvider.ITEMID + "=" + "'" + ID + "'",
                null,
                ImageProvider.IMAGEDATE + " DESC");

            column_path = cursor.getColumnIndex(ImageProvider.IMAGE);
            column_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(ImageProvider._ID);
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String filename = cursor.getString(column_path);
            java.io.File file = new java.io.File(filename);
            if(!file.exists()) {
                ImageID = cursor.getLong(column_index);
                getContentResolver().delete(ImageProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                        ImageProvider._ID + "=" + ImageID, null);
                Toast.makeText(LivestockDetails.this,
                        "There are missing images.  They have been removed from the database." ,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                viewimages();
            }
            else {                  
                Bitmap bitmapOrg = null;
                bitmapOrg = decodeFile(filename);

                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postScale(scale,scale);
                resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0,
                        bitmapOrg.getWidth(), bitmapOrg.getHeight(), matrix, true);

                Drawable delete = i.getDrawable();
                if(delete!= null) {
                    ((BitmapDrawable)i.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
                    i.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
                }
                else {
                    i.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
                }
                i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(240, 180));
                i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

Here is the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myaquarium.logger/myaquarium.logger.LivestockDetails}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at myaquarium.logger.LivestockDetails.viewimages(LivestockDetails.java:182)
at myaquarium.logger.LivestockDetails.onCreate(LivestockDetails.java:71)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
... 11 more
```

Comment: Which line is line 182 of LivestockDetails?

Comment: According to Eclipse it is:   column_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(ImageProvider._ID);

Comment: In fact thats the line it force closes at in the other page I got an error report for also.  

Keep in mind it works on several phones just fine and the one it is crashing on is identical to mine that works fine.

Comment: I cont figure this out. It's killing me.  Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  My content provider was screwed up.  I have two app, one is for my testing and one is for publishing.  I had the content provider for publishing pointing to my testing app so in the emulator it worked fine since the content provider was there but when someone purchsed my app the conntent provider was missing.  If only the error report gave more info.  When I replicated it on my emulator by uninstalling everything then only installing the main app the logcat told me ythe content provider could not be found.  Thats why it was crashing on the cursor every time.